# How to get rid of extra top bar in safari

Tags: safari, settings

My safari windows suddenly started to include an extra bar containing the bookmarks.  How do I remove this bar?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is toggled via the menu item *View > Show/Hide Favorites Bar*, accessible by pressing the shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.  It's the third item down in the *View* menu.